# Can't setup entry/initial module when using typescript with AMD

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, requirejs, amd

Let's say I have a main module that should be the starting point for all the other necessary modules on my page. This module is the `main-module.ts`.

I also have another module to format numbers, that's the `number-formatter.ts`. It's in the `services` folder.

I want the Typescript Compiler to compile a single file, starting from the `main-module.ts` and import everything it requires.

It does that, but the generated script doesn't execute the `main-module`. The correct way should be to generate the `main-module` as an anonymous module, that way, the requirejs will execute it ASAP. But it gives a name to the main module, and that ruins everything because no module is ever called.

### What's an anonymous module?

It's a module without a name. Example:

```
define(['i-need-this', 'i-also-need-this'], function(){
    // I do something here...
});
```

If the module has a name, it will only be executed when it's called, but if it's anonymous, it will execute ASAP.

Example of a module with a name:

```
define('this-is-my-name', ['i-need-this', 'i-also-need-this'], function(){
        // I do something here...
    });
```

The module above will only be executed if it's required (`require(['this-is-my-name'])`) or if some other module that was required has this module as a dependency.

## The source code

### main-module.ts

```
import { NumberFormatter } from '../services/number-formatter';

alert(
    NumberFormatter.toCurrency(
        NumberFormatter.round(19284.18, {roundBy: 10})
    )
);
```

### number-formatter.ts

```
export class NumberFormatter {

    static round(value: number, options?: {roundBy: number}): number {

        let defaultOptions: {roundBy: number} = {
            roundBy: 1};
        options = {...defaultOptions, ...options};

        return Math
            .round(value / options.roundBy) * options.roundBy;
    }

    static toCurrency(value: number, options?: {thousandsSeparator: string}): string {

        let defaultOptions: {thousandsSeparator: string} = {
            thousandsSeparator: '.'};
        options = {...defaultOptions, ...options};

        return value
            .toFixed(2)
            .toString()
            .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ";")
            .replace(/\./g, ",")
            .replace(/\;/g, options.thousandsSeparator);
    }

}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es5",
            "scripthost",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "dist/script.js",
        "module": "AMD",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/scripts/main-module.ts"
    ]
}
```

## The generated code

**Don't freak out!** There's a lot of stuff in the generated code, most of it is just converting everything to ES5. What's important here is that the main-module is named as `main-module`. If we just remove that name, everything works as expected.

### script.js

```
var __assign = (this && this.__assign) || Object.assign || function(t) {
    for (var s, i = 1, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        s = arguments[i];
        for (var p in s) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(s, p))
            t[p] = s[p];
    }
    return t;
};
define("services/number-formatter", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var NumberFormatter = /** @class */ (function () {
        function NumberFormatter() {
        }
        NumberFormatter.round = function (value, options) {
            var defaultOptions = {
                roundBy: 1
            };
            options = __assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
            return Math
                .round(value / options.roundBy) * options.roundBy;
        };
        NumberFormatter.toCurrency = function (value, options) {
            var defaultOptions = {
                thousandsSeparator: '.'
            };
            options = __assign({}, defaultOptions, options);
            return value
                .toFixed(2)
                .toString()
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ";")
                .replace(/\./g, ",")
                .replace(/\;/g, options.thousandsSeparator);
        };
        return NumberFormatter;
    }());
    exports.NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter;
});
define("main-module", ["require", "exports", "services/number-formatter"], function (require, exports, number_formatter_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    alert(number_formatter_1.NumberFormatter.toCurrency(number_formatter_1.NumberFormatter.round(19284.18, { roundBy: 10 })));
});
```